# Run multiple tasks sequentially after emitter response

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I am trying to create a communication controller for a hardware device that always responds with some delay. If I would only request one value, I could create a `Single<ByteArray>` and do the final conversion in `.subscribe{ ...}`.

But when I request more than one value I need to make sure that the second request happens *after* the first request has been fully closed.

Is that something that I can do with RxJava, e.g. [defer](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/defer.html)? Or should I create a queue on my own and handle the sequence of events manually with my queue?

We're using RxJava anyway (and I'm obviously new to it) and of course it would be nice to use it for this purpose as well. But is that a good use-case?

Edit:

Code that I could use, but that wouldn't be generic enough:

```
hardware.write(byteArray)
    .subscribe(
        {
            hardware.receiveResult().take(1)
                .doFinally { /* dispose code */ }
                .subscribe(
                    { /* onSuccess */ }
                    { /* onError */ }
                .let { disposable = it }
        },
        { /* onError */ }
    )
```

All code for the next request in the queue could be put in the inner `onSuccess` and then the next one in that `onSuccess`. That would be executed sequentially but that wouldn't be generic enough. Any other class that makes a request would end up spoiling my sequence.

I am searching for a solution that builds up the queue automatic in the hardware communication controller class.

Comment: do you need to make second request just the same as first, but only after first closed. Or you need to use result of the first request in the second request?

Comment: The results are independent. But the hardware gets confused, if requests come in before the previous one was answered. So it must be after the ```.subscribe(onSuccess``` block was executed.

Comment: can you share some code what you've already have, or how it should be more or less

Comment: Just run those on a same thread like Schedulers.single()? Then emission of one item will block the thread so the second item will arrive only after the first one has been processed.

Comment: @BorisSafonov I added some code.

Comment: @Than I'll try that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long time passed, the project developed and we got a solution long time ago. Now I wanted to share it here:

```
fun writeSequential(data1: ByteArray, data2: ByteArray) {
    disposable = hardwareWrite(data1)
        .zipWith(hardwareWrite(data2))
        .subscribe(
            {
                /* handle results.
                  it.first will be the first response,
                  it.second the second. */
            },
            { /* handle error */ }
        )

    compositeDisposable.add(disposable)
}

fun hardwareWrite(data: ByteArray): Disposable {
    var emitter: SingleEmitter<ByteArray>? = null
    var single = Single.create<ByteArray> { emitter = it }

    return hardware.write(data)
        .subscribe(
            { hardwareRead(emitter) },
            { /* onError */ }
        ))
}

fun hardwareRead(emitter: SingleEmitter<ByteArray>): Disposable {
    return hardware.receiveResult()
        .take(1)
        .timeout( /* your timeout */ )
        .single( /* default value */ )
        .doFinally( /* cleanup queue */ )
        .subscribe(
            { emitter.onSuccess(it) }
            { emitter.onError(it) }
        )
}
```

The solution is not perfect and now I see that the middle part doesn't do anything with the disposable result.

Also in out example it's a bit more complicated as hardwareWrite doesn't fire immediatelly but gets queued. This way we assure that the hardware is accessed sequentially and the result don't get mixed up.

Still I hope this might help someone, who is looking for a solution, and is maybe new to kotlin and/or RxJava stuff (like I was in the beginning of the project).